# how to loop all Jquery data table rows to get the current table values to sent it the sever across all pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

[image]

I want to loop through all the rows of the below table, but unable to do it. below is my code,

```
let userData = document.querySelector("#user_table tbody")
Array.from(userData.rows).forEach(async (data) => {
console.log(data)
})
```

when i tried the above code, i found that it "userData.rows" returns only first 10 rows  and another 4 rows data in the second pagination is not counted. As you clearly see i have textbox inside the final column td which is editable field, so i want to loop all 14 rows to get the updated data (Sequence no) to sent it to the server.

I have also tried the below method,

```
var table =  $("#user_table").DataTable({})
var data = table.rows().data();
data.each(function (value, index) {
console.log(`For index ${index}, data value is ${value}`);
});
```

but it returns the server side data only. I want to take the current table row across all pages and loop it to get the sequence no to update the server.

How can i achieve this behavior ?

Comment: You need to use the `onDraw()` method which will allow you to run a function on each page / time the datatable is drawn.

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to do that ?

Comment: Is the content in the DOM? As long as it is in the DOM you should be able to loop over it. So `let userData = document.querySelector("#user_table tbody")` should work but I assume when you paginate that refreshes the table view (if this data is sent to the client but not in the DOM necessarily then there will be a possibly easier method of trying to retrieve it). It's just a bit confusing. We need to see your markup and maybe the data.